# JFrame displaying incorrect contents

Tags: java, swing, awt, jframe, layout-manager

I am writing a chess program, and I am at the point where I am dealing with promoting a pawn. When a pawn reaches the final rank, a new jframe is supposed to pop up allowing the user to select what peice he wants the pawn to be promoted to. The problem is, when I create this frame from my main method, it displays just fine, but when I create it within my mouselistener code, it displays exactly whats behind it on the screen, and i have no idea why. Here is my relevant code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Example extends JFrame {

private SquarePanel[][] squares;
private Colors colors;

public Example () {
    super();
    colors = new Colors();
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container con = this.getContentPane();
    setSize(800,800);
    setLocation(0,0);
    con.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
    SquarePanel pane = null;
    SquarePanel lastpanel = null;
    squares = new SquarePanel[8][8];
    int color = colors.WHITE;

    for(int i = 7; i >= 0; --i) {   

        if(color == colors.WHITE)
            color = colors.BLACK;
        else
            color = colors.WHITE;

        for(int j = 0; j <= 7; ++j) {

            if(color == colors.WHITE)
                color = colors.BLACK;
            else
                color = colors.WHITE;

            lastpanel = new SquarePanel(color,j,i);
            pane = lastpanel;               
            con.add(pane);
            squares[j][i] = pane;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
            squares[j][i].setResident("pawn");
            //System.out.println(squares[j][i].getResident());
            //squares[j][i].repaint();
        }
    }

    MouseListener listener = new MoveListener(this, squares);
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
            squares[i][j].addMouseListener(listener);
    setVisible(true);
    PromotionFrame pf = new PromotionFrame(this, 1);
    String p = null;

    while(p == null) {
        p = pf.getPiece();
    }

    pf.dispose();
}

public class SquarePanel extends JPanel {
    private ImageIcon content;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int color;
    private String resident;
    private Colors colors;

    public SquarePanel(int color, int x, int y) {
        content = null;
        resident = null;
        this.color = color;
                    colors = new Colors();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        Border blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
        setBorder(blackline);
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        if(color == colors.WHITE)
            g.setColor(Color.white);
        else
            g.setColor(Color.green);

        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        //System.out.println("here");
    }

    public String getResident() {
        return resident;
    }

    public void setResident(String p) {
        resident = p;

        if(p == null)
            removeAll();
        else
            add(new JLabel(p));
    }

    public int getXCoordinate() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getYCoordinate() {
        return y;
    }
}

private class Colors {
    public int BLACK = 0;
    public int WHITE = 1;
}

public class MoveListener implements MouseListener {
    private int first_click;
    private SquarePanel first_source;
    private JFrame frame;
    private int turn;
    private SquarePanel[][] squares;

    public MoveListener(JFrame f, SquarePanel[][] s) {
        first_click = 0;
        this.frame = f;
        turn = colors.WHITE;
        squares = s;
    }


    /* Empty method definition. */
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        SquarePanel p = (SquarePanel)e.getSource();
        ImageIcon content = null;

        if(first_click == 0) {
            first_source = p;
            ++first_click;
            p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.cyan,4));
        }
        else {
            first_click = 0;
            first_source.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            //System.out.println(turn == colors.WHITE ? "White" : "Black");

            if(p.getResident().equals("pawn") && (p.getYCoordinate() == 7 || p.getYCoordinate() == 0)) {
                PromotionFrame pframe = new PromotionFrame(frame, colors.WHITE);
                String piece;

                do {
                    piece = pframe.getPiece();
                }
                while(piece == null);

                System.out.println(piece);
                pframe.dispose();
                p.setResident(piece);
            }

        }

    }

    /* Empty method definition. */
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    /* Empty method definition. */
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    /* Empty method definition. */
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

}

public class PromotionFrame extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
    private JFrame master;
    private String piece;

    public PromotionFrame(JFrame master, int color) {
        super();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        Container con = this.getContentPane();
        setSize(400,200);
        this.master = master;
        setLocation(master.getX()+master.getWidth()/2-200,master.getY()+master.getHeight()/2-100);
        setLocation(0,0);
        con.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));
        ImageIcon imgicon1;
        Image img1;
        Image newimg;
        ImageIcon img;
        ImageLabel label;
        piece = null;

        label = new ImageLabel("queen");
        label.addMouseListener(this);
        con.add(label);
        label = new ImageLabel("rook");
        label.addMouseListener(this);
        con.add(label);
        label = new ImageLabel("bishop");
        label.addMouseListener(this);
        con.add(label);
        label = new ImageLabel("knight");
        label.addMouseListener(this);
        con.add(label);

        this.show();
    }

    public String getPiece() {
        return piece;
    }

    /* Empty method definition. */
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        ImageLabel label = (ImageLabel)e.getSource();
        piece = label.getPiece();
    }

    /* Empty method definition. */
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    /* Empty method definition. */
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    /* Empty method definition. */
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    private class ImageLabel extends JLabel {
        private String piece;

        ImageLabel(String piece) {
            super(piece);
            this.piece = piece;
        }

        public String getPiece() {
            return piece;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Example();

}
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: are you sure **all** this code is strictly relevant to the question?

Comment: Too much code to look at and understand what your are doing. One comment is you should never have a do/while loop in the mainline of your GUI.

Comment: ok, here is an SSCCE. It doesnt work as it should, but its having the same problem I was having, so maaybe this will help diagnose it. What it does it when its created, it shows exactly whats behind it on screen, rather than a grid pattern.

Comment: i changed the source in my original post with the SSCCE version

Comment: ok, just not to waste anyones time, i found the small bug and it displays properly. to see my original bug, click on any square, and then click on a square in the top row, and you will see the promotion frame not displaying properly. when the program first runs, it will display a promotion frame to show you how it should look. to make it go away, click on any string within it.

Answer (score 1):

1) change main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Example example = new Example();
        }
    });
}
```

2)

your popup `PromotionFrame` probably simple to freeze, because inside `MouseListener` you created that on every MouseEvents, carefully with that, `MouseListener` generated unbeliveable amount of `Events`, then same amout of `PromotionFrame_s`

a)

```
class PromotionFrame extends JDialog implements MouseListener {
```

b)

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);



setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

c)

what did you means with thi code block one JLabel with four different definitions, then last is valid for current code

```
        label = new ImageLabel("queen");
        label.addMouseListener(this);
        con.add(label);
        label = new ImageLabel("rook");
        label.addMouseListener(this);
        con.add(label);
        label = new ImageLabel("bishop");
        label.addMouseListener(this);
        con.add(label);
        label = new ImageLabel("knight");
        label.addMouseListener(this);
        con.add(label);
```

d)

```
this.show();
```

to

```
this.setVisible(true);
```

e) create `PromotionFrame` code only once, re-use that for another Actions or Events

3) please reads again how [LayoutManagers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) works

Comment: i dont think your answer solves the problem. its true that there are 3 classes in my example, but they are all inner classes. if you copy the whole thing to a file called Example.java, it should compile and run. if you run it you will show the promotionframe correctly, then if you follow my instructions and click one square, then any square in the top row, promotionframe will pop up again, but not show correctly

Comment: also, the way its structured. promotionframe should only be created once per second mouse click, then it should poll for an answer, and go away once it receives an answer